# Passing by reference; why is the original object not changed?

Tags: php, object, pass-by-reference

If objects are passed by reference in PHP5, then why `$foo` below doesn't change?

```
$foo = array(1, 2, 3);
$foo = (object)$foo;

$x = $foo;            // $x = &$foo makes $foo (5)!
$x = (object)array(5);

print_r($foo); // still 1,2,3
```

---

so:

> Passing by reference not the same as
>   assign.

then why `$foo` below is `(100, 2, 3)` ?

```
$foo = array('xxx' => 1, 'yyy' => 2, 'zzz' => 3);
$foo = (object)$foo;

$x = $foo;            
$x->xxx = 100;

print_r($foo);
```

Comment: also, isn't this confusing? I mean I don't think that people who assign a object to a variable expect the object to change... unless they really know that PHP does this..

Comment: Once again: "passing by reference" usualy means passing somewhere. It's just common term. Tomalak explained already -- in 1st case during cast we have a *copy*.

Comment: Assignment by reference for objects is bloody confusing! That a cast gives you a new object is not.

Comment: Alex, in PHP nothing is *ever* passed by reference (or assigned by reference) unless PHP is told to do so. Objects are handled in a *reference-like* manner (because zvals of object only store a reference to the object data), but are in no way real references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
$x = $foo;   
$x = (object)array(5);
```

On the first rule $x is referenced to $foo; editing $x wil also edit $foo;
*(this is called "assign by reference", not "pass by reference" *1)*

```
$x->myProperty= "Hi";
```

Will cause $foo to also have a property "myProperty".

But on the next line you reference $x to a `new` object.
Effectively unreferencing $x from $foo, all changes you make to $x won't propogate to $foo.

*1: *When you call a function, the objects you pass to the functions are (in php5) "passed by reference"*

Comment: ok, so both assigning and passing by reference work, but to me assigning by reference feels "unnatural" without &. What if I wanted a copy of the object :P

Comment: I read the other correct answers and still couldn't see what I missed. +1 for the clear and simple explanation.

Comment: @Alex: You'd have to clone it.

Comment: $copy = clone $original;  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php for details.

Comment: @Alex: I agree. PHP's policy of assigning objects by reference makes my skin crawl.

Answer (score 2):

Not only are objects passed by reference; [they are also *assigned* by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) (which is what you're actually talking about):

> An exception to the usual assignment by value behaviour within PHP occurs with objects, which are assigned by reference in PHP 5.

However, in your first example, you're performing a cast operation. [This entails a copy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting):

> If a value of any other type is converted to an object, **a new instance** of the stdClass built-in class is created.

Arrays have their own type in PHP, and are not objects; thus the above rule applies.

Comment: Yes, cast gives us a copy -- and not reference. But the main OP's misunderstanding was in "passed by reference", which is not in provided code.

Comment: @gaRex: I know. I wouldn't say it's the "main" misunderstanding, but it's certainly a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Passing by reference not the same as assign.

Comment: Brevity is no substitute for thoroughness.

Comment: I prefer to give rod and not fish.

Comment: -1 Actually, as it turns out, this is wrong. PHP5 assigns objects by reference too.

Comment: Yes, you are write. But in this conrete example this impossible.

Comment: @gaRex: No. The assignment by reference happens just fine. It's the cast that is derailing the OP.

Answer (score 0):

At first you create an object by casting array into object. Then you create variable and pass that object by reference. But it does not work, because after that you assign some other object (casted from new array) into that second variable.

The result is that the reference changed to the second object, the first object itself was not changed.

See more details on the [Objects and References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

Comment: `$foo` is an array, not an object.

Comment: Ah, *after* the cast, sure. Sorry it's late. "At first" it was an array, not an object.

Comment: @Tomalak Ok, I have changed the answer so it may be more clear now.